# SQL Find all rows with foreign key 1 when any of foreign key 2 appear in second table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm up against the limit of my query writing expertise.
I have the following table in which the combination of extid + extdt us a sort of compound key:

```
 ents
 entid | extid |    extdt     | itemid |
 =======================================
  1000 |  100  | '2016-08-01' |   1    |
  1001 |  100  | '2016-08-01' |   2    |
  1002 |  200  | '2016-08-01' |   3    |
  1003 |  100  | '2016-08-02' |   4    |
  1004 |  200  | '2016-08-02' |   5    |
  1005 |  100  | '2016-08-02' |   6    |
```

So if itemid (1 or 2)are in the items table, the query will return both row 1000 and 1001. If itemid 3 exists, row 1002 is returned and so on...

```
items
    itemid | itemDesc | 
    ===================  
       1   |   'fu'   | 
       3   |   'bar'  |
       4   |  'blah'  |
```

With the above items table, I would expect to get back :

```
 entid | extid |    extdt     | itemid |
 =======================================
  1000 |  100  | '2016-08-01' |   1    |
  1001 |  100  | '2016-08-01' |   2    |
  1002 |  200  | '2016-08-01' |   3    |
  1003 |  100  | '2016-08-02' |   4    |
  1005 |  100  | '2016-08-02' |   6    |
```

I can't think of an aggregate function that would do what I'm looking for, nor does it seem like ANY/EXISTS would work. I'm getting hung up on the grouping the itemids... Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: @techspider is more than `INNER JOIN`

Comment: What is the logic for your output? Do you want to display Item 2, 6 rows even though they don't exist in items table?

Comment: your expected results make no sense -- why are the rows with itemid 2 and 6 included?

Comment: @Hogan I need to see items 2 and 6 because they're share  extid and extdt with items 1 and 4... someone shoehorned a business process into a table that wasn't made to accommodate it. Sadly, I can't fix that.

Comment: @NoTheOtherFry so the logic is the items with the extid of the items with the itemid in the items table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need get the composite keys matching your items, but include `DISTINCT` to avoid duplicates

```
SELECT  DISTINCT extid,  extdt
FROM ents
JOIN items
  ON ents.itemid = items.itemid
```

Now you retrive every row matching the selected composite key

```
SELECT *
FROM ents
JOIN ( SELECT  DISTINCT extid,  extdt
       FROM ents
       JOIN items
         ON ents.itemid = items.itemid 
     ) comp_key
 ON ents.extid = comp_key.extid
AND ents.extdt = comp_key.extdt
```

Comment: This did it! (but I didn't see the answer until I worked through it with the other suggestions and started to post my own) 
First get all of the extid and extdt combinations that have itemid in items. Then go back and join ents on the extid and extdt. 
Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from ents e1 
where e1.extid in
    (select extid 
     from ents e2 
     where e2.itemid in (select itemid from items))
```

Maybe? You could also modify the last inner query for the item ids you specificly want.

Comment: What I think he wants is, for the item ids he picks, he wants to display all rows with the matching extid. So one of the possible way to do it is joining ents table twice(I posted the code above).

Comment: This was immensely helpful in getting me to look at the problem a little differently. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Just join em up based on the logic

```
SELECT e.*
-- records from the ents table
FROM ents e
-- with an extid that matches
JOIN ents extid on e.extid = extid.extid
-- all the records with an itemid in the items table.
JOIN items i on extid.itemid = i.itemid
```

if the unique key is id and date then use

```
JOIN ents extid on e.extid = extid.extid and e.extdt = extid.extdt
```

Comment: This was really useful for seeing the problem as smaller chunks than I was  visualizing before. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

From your description (but not the example, which seems to contradict it):

```
SELECT e.*
FROM item i
JOIN ent e ON e.itemid = i.itemid
```

But I suspect the problem isn't that simple?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM [Test].[dbo].[ents] e,[Test].[dbo].[items] i
WHERE e.extid in (SELECT extid from [Test].[dbo].[ents] oe where oe.itemid=i.itemid)
and e.extdt in (SELECT extdt from [Test].[dbo].[ents] oe where oe.itemid=i.itemid)
order by itemid
```

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.